# Java: Counting clicks on button

Tags: java, button

I am trying to do something similiar as cookie clicker, nevertheless it does not work. I have not managed to create a "counter" that shows the amount of clicks. This is what I got hitherto, any ideas?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Stocks implements ActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Stocks().createGui();
        }
    });

}

public void createGui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Clicker");
    frame.setSize(175, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Click this");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
    panel.add(button1, c);
    button1.addActionListener(this);

}
```

Comment: you'll need to show us the rest of your code. You've implemented ActionListener there, so I assume you also have an actionPerformed somewhere. Mind showing it to us?

Comment: It is empty, it's where the counter would be. That is my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, your actionPerformed method is empty, meaning you coded your application to do nothing when the button is clicked.

This answer is assuming you only have one component using that class as ActionListener:

In earlier versions of Java, it would be:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        counter++;
}
```

Java 8, however, provides us with Lambda expressions, and allows this to be a lot easier (with less code).

```
button1.addActionListener(event -> counter++);
```

You don't need to create an implementation of ActionListener, Java 'll take care of this for you. If you write your code like this, it is even easier if you have more components using that class as ActionListener, since you won't be able to mix them up.

If you need them to call shared parts of code, you can still call methods from within the Lambda expression

```
button1.addActionListener(event -> {callSharedMethod(); counter++;});
```

In this example, first the shared method will be called. After that, the counter will be augmented, which will/might only be done from clicking this button.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a variable `int cnt = 0;` inside your Stocks class and everytime someone clicks on the button you increase `cnt` by one in the `actionPerformed` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should first add a counter as a attribute of your class `Stock``

```
public class Stocks {
    private int counter;
```

Initialize counter variable with 0:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    this.counter = 0;
```

And then add the action listener to increase the variable:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                counter++;
            }
        });
```

Comment: But how do I make it to show up above the button as someone is clicking?

Comment: For that you need to have a JTextfield to show the number and in the ActionListener you update the TextField

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody proposed resolving this by inheritance. The button you want **is a** `JButton` but slightly more specialized (it must count the number of clicks performed on itself).

```
public final class CountButton extends JButton {

    private int counter = 0;

    public CountButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                counter++;
            }
        });
    }

    public final int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```